# What does the value of LIME mean?

Tags: python, nlp, lime

I'm exploring the workings of **LIME** in **NLP** models to understand how it elucidates positive and negative words.

I possess a trove of documents resembling this excerpt:

> The UN children’s agency says the 'world cannot stand by and watch' the suffering in Gaza.

> 'Intensifying conflict, malnutrition, and disease in Gaza are creating a deadly cycle that is threatening over 1.1 million children,' UNICEF said in a social media post.

> At least 249 Palestinians have been killed and 510 wounded in the previous 24 hours in Gaza, the health ministry says."

My classification model distinguishes each document as either "**United Nation Related**" or "**NON-UN Related**" denoted by labels **1** (United Nation Related) or **0** (NON-UN).

Here's a snippet of the code implementation:

```py
exp = explainer.explain_instance(X_test.values[i], clf.predict_proba, num_features=LIMEMaxFeatures)
lst = exp.as_list()
```

Initially, everything seems fine. However, an issue arises when employing LIME for certain documents classified as NON-UN Related.

Consider this example:

> "Guterres invoked this responsibility, saying he believed the
> situation in Israel and the occupied Palestinian territories, 'may
> aggravate existing threats to the maintenance of international peace
> and security'."

Despite this text, my model classifies it as **NON-UN** Related. Upon using LIME to delve into the reasons behind this classification, the results are as follows:

```
    Word        Value
    occupied    -0.130118107160623
    situation   -0.284915997715762
    Guterres    0.22668070156952
    Gaza        0.144198872750898
```

My query pertains to the word "Guterres," where the LIME value is **POSITIVE**. Does this imply that "Guterres" supports the decision of label **0** prediction (NON-UN Related)? *In essence, does a higher value for "Guterres" signify the model's stronger confidence in labeling the document as NON-UN Related?*

Alternatively, does the **POSITIVE** value for "Guterres" signify a tendency towards label **1** (United Nation Related)? *Does a higher positive value for "Guterres" indicate a stronger inclination towards labeling the document as United Nation Related?*

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

Based on the documentation of LIME

https://lime-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lime.html

```
(label=1, **kwargs)
```

`as_list` function takes a parameter for the label, by default it targets **Label = 1**

so the Positive values mean they are evidence for the **Label = 1**
and negative means evidence for **Label NOT = 1**